# Flutter and Supabase - OAuth deep link not working

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth, deep-linking, supabase

I have set up OAuth with my Flutter app and Supabase. It works on the web... I sign in to the provider and I'm redirected to my website with the credential. However, in iOS, it does not work. I sign in to the provider and am still redirected to the website instead of the app. I added `CFBundleURLSchemes` to the `Info.plist` and associated domains, but that did not work. This is the function I use, which is what the Supabase example shows:

```
Supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(
  pkg.Provider.apple,
  redirectTo: kIsWeb ? null : '<Bundle url>://login-callback/',
);
```

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>*bundle id*</string>
          <string>domain.com</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. In a [separate guide for Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-flutter#setup-deep-links), it mentions needing to add `'<Bundle url>://login-callback/'` as a `redirect_url` on the server itself. With self-hosting, this shows up as `ADDITIONAL_REDIRECTURLS` in `.env`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the scheme you used in the info.plist file? which is needed for the os to know to open URL with that scheme in this app. Which is as follows:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>YourSchemeHere</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and this is the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) about that

Comment: Yes I have that added and I have my website url in it as well as the bundle url. But according to Supabase documentation I shouldn’t even have to do that, it’s just supposed to work.

Comment: @Globe Would you tell me where you got "according to Supabase documentation I shouldn't even have to do that" from? Because it is actually a requirement. The cause of deeplink not working is probably because there is an error in the configuration here. What do you have in the `YourSchemeHere` section?

Comment: I added that to the bottom of the question for you. As for the Supabase documentation, here (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/auth-signinwithoauth) is the function that says all you need to login with OAuth is the function that I'm using. It doesn't mention needing to add more things.